# WAS console not available from Bluemix service dashboard

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, application-server, ibm-was-oc

I have a WebSphere Application Server service on Bluemix. From the dashboard, the link to the WAS admin console does not work (browser opens and request times out). I cannot ping the console's IP address. However, three days prior to this problem, the link worked successfully.

Actions I have taken:

1. Turned OFF my local firewall.  Result was the same as above.
2. Closed all other VPNs except OpenVPN.  Result was the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to start the OpenVPN client as an administrator (this solved the problem). Starting the client as a non-admin causes connection issues.